# Removing Subscribers from NServiceBus/Raven

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

Using NserviceBus 3.3 with Raven for subscription persistence.

I'm creating a prototype application that will consume messages from a publisher in our test environment.  The application will only be used for a few weeks, at which point it may be (essentially) thrown away in its current form.

I don't want the publisher to continue to send messages to the outbound queue for this subscriber.  In effect, I want its existence to be completely removed from the system.

How would I go about removing all knowledge of this subscriber from the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to manage subscriptions manually.

Have a look at the [PubSub sample](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/master/Samples/PubSub), specifically [this file](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/Samples/PubSub/Subscriber2/Subscriber2Endpoint.cs) and you also need to tell the bus [not to autosubscribe](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/Samples/PubSub/Subscriber2/EndpointConfig.cs#L15), this sample should provide you with all the code required to do this.

Comment: So once it's in there, it can't be removed?  You need to know that you may want to unsubscribe in the future?

Comment: You can still call `Bus.Unsubscribe<T>()` from anywhere in the code.

Comment: You can also remove the RavenDb document

Comment: we use powershell + the ravendb rest api to clear the subscriptions, then we simply restart the services.

Comment: @Marius Do you have an example you can share?

Answer (score 0):

The link to the PubSub article is broken. Here is the new link: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Msmq.Samples/tree/master/PubSub